# Prevent RDC from installing new keyboard layouts

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop, keyboard-layout

My work PC and my home PC have different keyboard layouts.

Because of this, when I connect from one PC to another using RDC, Windows installs a second keyboard layout on the PC being connected, and it'll remain there even after I disconnect.

This drives me nuts, since Windows has a bad habit of changing the active layout when you switch applications. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard layout change is by design, and I don't know of a solution, except for using instead of RDC another remote desktop solution such as VNC.

You might try to see if this behavior is not improved in the latest [Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 client](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084), but I wouldn't hope for too much.

The only help I can offer is the information that in Windows Vista it's possible to configure international settings from the command line. Writing such a script might simplify getting rid of the unwanted keyboard. If this interests you, see this [article](http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/vista/vista_tools/vista_command_line_international_configuration.mspx).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I just happened to find the solution:

[a registry key exists for that very problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924852)

To change the default behavior to obtain the **Default input language** setting from the default user profile, you must set a registry entry value on the terminal server. To do this, follow these steps:

- On the terminal server, click **Start**, click **Run**, type regedit, and then click **OK**.
- Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout**

- On the **Edit** menu, click **Add Value**, and then add the following registry information:
  Value name: IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout
  Data type: REG_DWORD
  Value data: 1

When the IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout entry is set to 1, new user profiles inherit the **Default input language** setting from the default user profile that the user account uses.